# How to keep all the settings of a Form when it is re-opened

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm creating a windows application with VB.NET, and my application got many forms. Let's say there is a main form which require the users set all the parameters. And after the settings is finished then the user click a `Start` button, then another form with all the calculated results shown will pop up. However in the result form, there is a `Next Run` button which will lead the user back to the initial main form to do perform another run. Basically it is like a circular loop.

Below is my code, for the main form

```
Public Class FormMain

    Private Sub OpenResult_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenResult.Click
        Result.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

for the result form

```
Public Class Result

    Private Sub OpenMain_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenMain.Click
        Main.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the project `shutdown mode` has been changed to `When last form closes`.

In such case, if I want to keep all the settings after I close the main form, what I want think of is just to save all the parameters into the variables and then assign the variables to the corresponding parameters next time when I reopen it. Is there another other better ways to keep all the settings?

Another way I can think of is that instead of `close` it, I could make it `invisible`. However, when I close the result form, the whole application is while not being closed since the main form is still running (invisible only). How should I address this?

Any inputs will help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at `My.Settings`

Answer (score 0):

If the calculation page doesn't change settings on the start page, you could just put the "save settings" code in the start form's "frmStart_FormClosing" event and put the "restore settings" code in the "frmStart_Load" event. A sample for saving size and position is below - but make sure you create the application settings before you try to save to or read from them. This works even if you are closing and re-loading the form while other forms are active, it doesn't wait for the application exit to fire. In this case the settings types are system.drawing.point and system.drawing.size.

```
Private Sub frmCash_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  If My.Settings.NewCashWindowSize.Width > 100 And My.Settings.NewCashWindowSize.Height > 100 Then
     Me.Height = My.Settings.NewCashWindowSize.Height
     Me.Width = My.Settings.NewCashWindowSize.Width
  End If
  If My.Settings.NewCashWindowPoint.X > -1 And My.Settings.NewCashWindowPoint.Y > -1 _
      And Screen.GetBounds(Me).Contains(My.Settings.NewCashWindowPoint) Then
     Me.Location = My.Settings.NewCashWindowPoint
  End If
 ...
End Sub

Private Sub frmCash_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
  My.Settings.NewCashWindowSize = New System.Drawing.Size(Me.Width, Me.Height)
  My.Settings.NewCashWindowPoint = Me.Location
End Sub
```